# Need to debug db_insert but no error given

Tags: php, database, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a custom module in a D7 installation.

In the submit function I'm doing the following:

```
my_custom_block_get_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

$d = db_insert('db_launch')
->fields(array(
'uniq' => $uniq
))
->execute();
```

After executing the code, I get no errors in the error log, and the sites returns the standard "This website has encountered an error".

Does anyone have idea how I can debug this? I tried a try catch block but that didn't return anything.

Thanks,

Comment: Which type your `uniq` field is? Maybe you trying to set string to a field which should be as int.

Comment: $q = db_insert('my_db')->fields(array('uniq','date'));
$q->values(array(
'uniq'=> $uniq,
'date' => $query['date'] 
));
$q->execute();

Comment: that syntax works better.  No idea why drupal would prevent the developer seeing sql errors.  Had to debug this by inserting values into a db myself.

Comment: @rix: That's strange behaviour, I always use the syntax in your original question and if I've made a mistake I always see the error. Do you have any modules installed that might be a dev release (these might be interfering)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this code, you should try doing it this way:

```
$query = db_insert('db_launch')
->fields(array(
'uniq' => $uniq
));

echo (string) $query ; // This will output your query that would be created with an insert.

$d = $query->execute(); // and later on you can attach the output result.
```

Note that, this will return the query with placeholders. If you wish to obtain the queries with actual values, you should have `devel.module` enabled and then:

```
echo dpq($query) ; // This will output your query without placeholders
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this because it seems like the most sensible answer but since i don't use Drupal anymore (for reasons like this) I have no idea if it actually works :)

Comment: `dpq($query)` does not work in this context. It throws an exception because `dpq` requires an object of type `SelectQueryInterface`, and `db_insert` returns `InsertQuery` which does not implement it, so you get an exception. However, `echo (string)$query` works, even though it does not print placeholders. I don't know a way to print out a full query, since all the relevant fields are protected.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this code you should try this.

```
$query = db_insert('db_launch')
 ->fields(array(
    'uniq' => $uniq
));
$res = $query->execute();
echo $res;
```

This code print the auto increment id of **db_launch** table.